# Need to redirect to 403 if / is not supplied by included conf

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I should say that i'm very new to Nginx so i'm sorry if this is a stupid question.

In my Nginx configuration I use includes to determine wether or not I export a webpage.
If export the web page I do I want the http://hostname/ to redirect to http://hostname/ui/.

If not I would like to return 403 error code.

The code in my included ui.conf contains this location block:

```
location = / {
  return 302 " /ui";
}
```

I want to define default behaviour when this is not included but when I add a `location /` in my regular nginx.conf I get an error saying I can't define the same location twice.

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

So what ended up working is using

```
location = / {
}
```

in my ui.conf file
and

```
location / {
}
```

In my main conf file.